# Hydrogen Package on Atom (Windows) - Cannot Interrupt Python Kernel

Tags: python, atom-editor, interrupt, hydrogen

Cannot interrupt python kernel using hydrogen package on atom, on windows. This is a known issue since 2017, still unresolved (https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/597).

I was wondering if anyone on here had found a solution and/or if anyone knows of a comparable IDE.

Jupyter nb is quite slow when editing large files for me. Hydrogen runs much more smoothly with comparable functionality (can run blocks of code at a time, can fold using specific identifiers, can skip from folded section to folded section using key binds = replicates a notebook). But the inability to interrupt is an issue. So, just looking for an alternative (or a fix).

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. We don't really do software recommendations on SO, but if you exhaust your own research and still can't find anything that meets your specific requirements, we might be able to help. Off the top of my head, you might look into PyCharm and VSCode - I think they both have IPython plugins. Check out [ask] and [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: You mean "IPython kernel", right? I'm not aware of any plain Python kernels.

Comment: Did you try the workaround from the GitHub thread? *‘At the moment, the best workaround if you depend on this functionality is to install a notebook server and use only "remote" kernels.’*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes i meant IPython kernel. I had tried the github workaround before and could not get it to work, but was able to figure it out. That said, the VSCode recommendation was also great.